# Logitech Mouse Repeat with Toggle

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I already tried and always ended up by infinite loop.

my code:

```
toggle_button = 5
button_toggled = false
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == toggle_button then
        button_toggled = not button_toggled
        if button_toggled then
            while button_toggled do
            OutputLogMessage(tostring(button_toggled))
            Sleep(50)
            end
        else
            button_toggled = not button_toggled
        end 
    end
end
```

Comment: The next invocation of `OnEvent()` will not happen until you exit from previous `OnEvent()`

Comment: What logic do you want to implement?